# Join the first table that have multiple foreign key from second table

Tags: postgresql

I confuse how to make the question based on my problem.

```
TABLE1
id             pk
caption
video_url      fk
image_url      fk
gif_url        fk

TABLE2
id             pk
url_storage
```

Example data in table:

```
TABLE1
id      caption     video_url     image_url     gif_url
5        HAHA          null           1            2


TABLE2
id      url_storage
1      www.google.com
2     www.facebook.com
```

I join them using `Full Join`, but image_url and gif_url still only show the id. So, how to join both tables?

Comment: 'I join them using Full Join - I guess you are using postgresql only since mysql does not have FULL JOIN I have removed mysql tag.

Comment: Please publish the query you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get all the URL listed using below query. You might have to alter the select clause to choose only the fields that you need.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.image_url = t2.id 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t3 on t1.gif_url = t3.id
```

Comment: It works!!!, another question, why do you use `LEFT JOIN` than `FULL JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: [PostgreSQL Joins](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-joins/)